# Transformation and/or Winsorizing?

Tags: t-test, spss, outliers, winsorizing

I want to compare two group of 24 and 28 people with t-test on type of activity (5 different's types of activity and a total), later one the same value will be use in regression logistic.

If you have in your data set two variables with a normal distribution but outliers and one varialbe with a non-normal distribution and outlier.

Can you transform the one with a non-normal distribution, wisorize the others with outliers and keep the normal one normal?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  Please tell us.